# Curved plane surface in CSS3 or Three.js?

Tags: css, 3d, three.js

How can I create a *curved plane surface* (like the one pictured) using CSS3 or Three.js?

[image: curved surface]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var width = 100, height = 100, width_segments =1, height_segments = 100;
var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height, width_segments, height_segments);

for(var i=0; i<plane.vertices.length/2; i++) {
    plane.vertices[2*i].position.z = Math.pow(2, i/20);
    plane.vertices[2*i+1].position.z = Math.pow(2, i/20);
}

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(plane, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x888888}));
mesh.doubleSided = true;
mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI/2-0.5;
scene.add(mesh);
```

You create geometry, and displace it's vertices the way you would like to. For creating curved surface you could use 'sin' or 'cos' functions, or exponential, as I showed.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Very nice solution thanks. Do you think it is possible to achieve this kind of quality (interaction, render etc.) with three.js or should I go another route? http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/interactive/2011/mar/22/middle-east-protest-interactive-timeline

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Those "pins" could be rendered as Sprites in Three.js. Interaction should really be simple since Three.js provides Ray class and gives you as much freedom as needed. I would go with webGL/Three.js, better than css3, deffinately.

Comment: Thanks, I hope I will be able to achieve the same level of quality using webGL.

Comment: I just noticed that grey-striped surface is completely static.
You could maybe draw it with simple 2D. Only black horizontal lines and pins should be drawn, and text. Think about it. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is a correct observation :) Hmm, I wonder if I can get the perspective for the horizontal lines and pins working using only SVG?

Comment: That is the point. If you look closer, there is no actual perspective. It's only mater of position on canvas and scale. :]
Also, drawing back-to-front order, but those are easy and 2d things.

Comment: Any idea on how I would place pins and lines algorithmically in 2D space? Lets say I draw the image in photoshop. How would you determine the position and size of a pin for a given date?

Comment: That's up to you. Those are 'just' boring calculations. Date span, current looking date span and determining position for each pin.

Array of pins, each with date, calculate what you could see in current position on date-bar, go through array and draw.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe they are not boring in the sense that they follow non-linear functions? I mean, I would ideally like all attributes to follow a smooth bezier?

Comment: Have't thought of bezier, that is probably best way to get their position parametrically. But you can also simplify it by assuming they're all on circle path.