# how to make a curved plane in threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, plane

I am projected a video into 3d geometry using threejs. The footage is from a gopro, so it's got a field of view of maybe 120degrees, so what I want is to be looking as if the footage were wrapped such that it bent a little at the sides, top and bottom (like looking from the inside of a sphere and the video were wrapped around only a portion of that sphere.

I've tried using a torus and sphere, but since the video doesn't completely wrap, it doesn't do quite what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395690/curved-plane-surface-in-css3-or-three-js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably should try to look for the right equation but, by the time being, you should be able to get something working with something like this:

```
new THREE.SphereGeometry(75, 16, 8, 0, 2, 1, 1.2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EHEap/