# Change text curve direction three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created 3D text with three.js. My problem is that curve direction is not propertly:

[image: text3D]

**CODE:**

```
            var textLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
            textLoader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {
                var theText = "My example text";
                var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( theText, {
                    size: 128,
                    height: 50,
                    curveSegments: 4,
                    font: font
                });

                var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    color: 0x62254a
                });
                var text3D = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);

                var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
                var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
                var angle = Math.PI / 6;

                var modifier = new THREE.BendModifier();
                modifier.set(direction, axis, angle).modify( text3D.geometry );

                group.add( text3D );
                scene.add( group );
            } );
```

...and I need to create text curve like in this [example](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/#webgl_modifier_bend).

Comment: Have you tried changing the axis' vector?
Try `var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);`
Or `var direction = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0);`

Comment: yes, but this changes doesn't change the curve direction :/

Comment: The example you want to recreate has been made with an old version of Three.js and transformation matrices don't work the same way. You can try [MOD3](https://github.com/foo123/MOD3) as [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1680) issue suggests. 
You could also try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395690/curved-plane-surface-in-css3-or-three-js) approach.