# ThreeJS: How to bend a 2d shape?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Say I make a simple shape like so:

```
var Shape = new THREE.Shape();
Shape.lineTo(0, 4);
Shape.lineTo(4, 4);
Shape.lineTo(4, 0);
Shape.lineTo(0, 0);
```

Is there a way to bend it so that rather being a flat square is it curved? Imagine a square piece of paper lying on a desk. If you lift up one end it is still a square piece of paper but it has become curved, that is the effect I'm after.

Comment: Have you considered loading in a 3D model instead of emulating it in 2D?

Comment: Specifically for the shape you've provided, it's just a simple plane, so you can use `THREE.PlaneGeometry()`/`THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry()` with some number of width and height segments, thus you can bend it at your wish.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395690/curved-plane-surface-in-css3-or-three-js

Comment: YES! Thank you :-)